# How to pass an object to a function that expects a file?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Often, I'll run into a problem where I want to pass an object to an imported function, but that function expects a file. So, I first write the object to a file, then pass the file as a parameter in the function call. Not only does this create a file which I need to remove, but it also interrupts piped workflows. I'd like to cut out the middleman and just pass the object to the function.

An example is `ggmsa::readSSfile()`, which transforms a string of dots and parentheses into a list that can be interpreted by `ggmsa::gghelix()`.

```
structure <- "..(.((((...)))).....((..))....)."
write(structure, file = "/user/data/structure.txt")
data <- ggmsa::readSSfile(file = "/user/data/structure.txt", type = "Vienna")
file.remove("/user/data/structure.txt")
ggmsa::gghelix(data)
```

Is there an argument structure that would allow me to "trick" the function? Something like this:

```
read_file(file = pseudo_write(object))
```

Comment: try using `textConnection` ie `data <- ggmsa::readSSfile(file = textConnection(structure), type = "Vienna")` Let me know if that works. Then I can add it to the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the function `textConnection`:

```
data <- ggmsa::readSSfile(file = textConnection(structure), type = "Vienna")
```

This will aleviate the writing part and the removing part